# How to test confguration of static resources in Spring MVC test framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, testing, spring-test

I am using Spring MVC test framework for Integrated testing of my Spring Controllers. Below is the code for my `Controller` and its `Test` currently using.

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView goLogin(){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("login");
    mv.addObject("loginForm", new loginForm());
    return mv;
}

@Test
public void goLoginPage() throws Exception{
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/login")).andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/template/default.jsp"))
    .andExpect(model().attribute("loginForm", any(loginForm.class)));   
}
```

I am using `Apache Tiles` as view framework. Below is the layout configuration code for `loginForm` page.

```
<definition name="login" template="/WEB-INF/template/default.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Login - Spring Web Testing"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/tile/header.jsp"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tile/login_body.jsp"></put-attribute>
    <put-list-attribute name="javascripts">
        <add-attribute value="/static/script/jquery-2.1.4.js"></add-attribute>
    </put-list-attribute>
    <put-list-attribute name="stylesheets">
        <add-attribute value="/static/style/general.css" />
    </put-list-attribute>
</definition>
```

How can I test if `Javascript` and `stylesheet` files in  `Apache Tiles` configuration are correctly configured? And expect an error if file(s) are not found.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to test that through Spring MVC Test since there is no Servlet container and therefore no JSP rendering.

That said you could still use Spring MVC Test to test all of your controller logic and separately validate Tiles configuration by creating a full integration test (with an actual Servlet container running) that renders each page once and checks that it's fully rendered with all expected parts.